# How to use the CVS commitid feature?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I've noticed that newer versions of CVS use commitids.

I guess this is a recent addition - because 'back in the days' there was no such thing.

Googling around I find mostly comments related to CVSNT - but it seems that commitids are also present in standard open source CVS.

How can I take advantage of the commitid feature (in standard CVS)?

For example:

- How to display a diff between to commitids?
- How to list the files/version-numbers that are associated to a certain commitid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything in CVS itself that does anything with the commitid other than setting it.

Here's what the documentation says (`info cvs`):

> At `commit`, a unique commitid is placed in the RCS file inside the
>   repository. All files committed at once get the same commitid, a string
>   consisting only of hexadecimal digits (usually 16 in GNU CVS, 19 in
>   MirBSD and MirDebian GNU CVS).  FSF GNU CVS 1.11, MirOS GNU CVS 1.11,
>   and OpenBSD OpenCVS do not support commitids yet.  The commitid can be
>   retrieved with the `log` and `status` command; see *note log:: and
>   *note File status::.

Other tools can parse the output of `cvs log` and determine the commitid for a given commit. In particular, changes that were commited in a single `cvs commit` command will have the same commitid. I can imagine that being useful for tools that convert CVS repositories to other systems such as SVN or Git.

But such tools would  have to allow for repositories created by older versions of CVS that didn't have this feature. For example, one file I maintain in CVS has 211 commits, of which the first 186 don't have commitids; apparently that's when I switched to a newer version of CVS (late 2007 or early 2008).

Changes commited together should also share the same timestamp, though that's less reliable. Combining the timestamp with the author should a bit more reliable, but still not perfect.